# Использование this в JS

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой код:

```
<button onclick="ProfileEditor.saveEducation(this)"><span>Сохранить</span></button>
```

и его клиентский обработчик:

```
saveEducation: function(th){
        var formData = $(th).closest('form').serialize();
        console.log(formData);
        return false;
    },
```

Так вот, почему переданный this элемента не срабатывает для:

```
$(th).closest('form').serialize();
```

Вроде бы по принципам this - это указание на текущий исполняемый объект

Comment: В консоли нет чего-то вроде: "**ProfileEditor is not defined**"? Что-то мне подсказывает, что если вы свой "клиентский обработчик" разместите ниже кнопки, то всё сразу заработает.

P.S. Точнее даже не так... Скорее всего, объект "ProfileEditor" у вас находится внутри обёртки DOM-Ready. Попробуйте вынести его за пределы.

Comment: еще раз -

#делать onclick в разметке - очень плохая практика. *особенно когда используете jQuery.*

Comment: @eicto, это спорное утверждение, у такого способа есть свои минусы, но нельзя так категорично заявить, что это прям плохая практика, например весь мобильный gmail на onclick/onfocus/onsubmit и т.п.

Comment: но он и без jquery и есть конкретные причины, отсутствие Event как пример, не сбивайте ОП  с толку, к тому времени  как он поймет когда oncick хорошо выйдет ES6 :) это в Го тоже есть крайне плохие ходы - пустой треугольник например, но есть даны у которых это  чуть ли не стиль игры, что не дает младшей группе никакого повода пытаться делать так-же. как сказал один знакомый - говнокодить можно только архитекторам.

Comment: Про jQuery я согласен, но это максимум тянет на неуместное использование, а не «очень плохая практика», `e` там нет, его нигде нет, зато есть `event`. Так какие другие причины?

Comment: нужно держать объекты к которым обращаешься из таких функций в global

кстати насчет gmail

    > document.body.innerHTML.match(/onclick/g).length
    1

Comment: Единый namespace, например. onclick имеют право на существование, они решают свою задачу, данный подход вполне жизнеспособен и говорить, что это совсем плохо не корректно. Неуместно да. Ведь onclick это не императивный, а декларативный подход, как в Angular ;]

Тут парвильно сказать, что подход должен быть один, а не месиво. Повторюсь, у этого способа есть свои сильные/слабые стороны. Например есть очень элегантное и старое решение, передача опций через `onclick="return { foo: 'bar' }"`, конечно это не тоже самое, что у автора, но это одно из применений.

P.S. gmail — http://goo.gl/IlI9cz

Comment: это не единый namespace. namespace тут вообще ни причем. Насчет сильных сторон вы ничего не сказали, слабые стороны я назвал, есть и ещё несколько вроде того, что приложение получает бессчетное количество точек входа. Насчет ангуляр кстати - у них то как-раз с этим все нормально, событие ng-click таки не в рутовом scope выполняется и программист вполне себе представляет состояние.

пример покажите практического использования  `onclick="return { foo: 'bar' }"`

какой такой правильный this ? window что-ли ?

Comment: onclick тоже выполняет в «рутовом scope» (он же window). Про минусы я вам уже сказал, что event есть, обращения к глобальным объекту не аргумент, тут зависит от компетентности разработчика, он и на jQuery точно также может обращается к глобальным объектам/переменным/функциям. Плюсы? Кроссбраузерность, не нужно тащить jQuery, наглядность/декларативность, правильный this, чем не плюсы?

Comment: @RubaXa, пусть gmail и контакт делают что угожно, свою голову никто не отменял.  
Не знаю как у вас, а у меня университет оставил в первую очередь фразу "**в знании нет авторитетов**".